# Jinja templates syntax hilighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, jinja2

I'd like to adapt jinja.el to work with one-line comments using `##`. But my knowlege of elisp is bad. Who can help me? What do I want: i'd like to hilite

```
## some text
## {% include "_template.html" %}
```

as a commented out strings. But it works not fully correct. 1st line of snippet looks like comment out while 2nd - not. Here is what i've got:

[image]

And here is a part of jinja.el taken from Jinja's git repo plus my regexp for `##`:

```
(defconst jinja-font-lock-keywords
  (list
;   (cons (rx "{% comment %}" (submatch (0+ anything))
;             "{% endcomment %}") (list 1 font-lock-comment-face))
   '("{%-?\\|-?%}\\|{{\\|}}" . font-lock-preprocessor-face)
   '("{# ?\\(.*?\\) ?#}" . (1 font-lock-comment-face))
   '("## ?\\(.*\\)" . (1 font-lock-comment-face))
   '("{#\\|#}" . font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)
   '("##" . font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)
   ;; first word in a block is a command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I found solution. Change

```
'("## ?\\(.*\\)" . (1 font-lock-comment-face))
```

to

```
'("## ?\\(.*\\)" . (1 font-lock-comment-face t))
```

ie setting 'override' parameter to true solves me question.